# how to use the geany debugger?

Tags: debugging, documentation, geany

I am new to debugging and I need to how to use the debugger in geany IDE. Is there any documentation or a video available in the internet related to the geany debugger? I have surfed everywhere but I couldn't find anything understandable. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You mean this plugin? -> http://plugins.geany.org/debugger.html

Comment: yes. And that site doesn't have any clear documentation.

Answer (score 11):

I have come across this problem myself.

- *Compiler*: gcc
- *Debugger*: gdb
- *Editor*: geany

Assuming you have installed `gcc` and `gdb` by this.

Install **gcc** and **gdb**

```
sudo apt install gcc gdb
```

To install **geany**:

```
sudo apt install geany
```

To install the **plugins for geany**:

```
sudo apt install geany-plugins
```

Restart geany if open now.

To activate the debugger in geany: *menu->tools->plugin manager*
, checkbox the debugger.

Change the build commands to include the -g flag:

*menu->build->build commands*

Set the compile command to:

```
gcc -g -Wall -c "%f"
```

Set the build command to:

```
gcc -g -Wall -o "%e" "%f"
```

And now you can set breakpoints in your code by clicking next to the line numbers. You will see a red square.

In the *menu->view->show message window*
You will have a tab called debug.

Click the debug tab then click the target tab.

Choose your target(if you build "example.c" and set output to "example" which you would normally run with "./example" you would choose "example" as target.

On the right side of that window you can start the debugging.

Comment: I've followed those instructions but I don't have any tab called "debug".

Comment: Greate explanation. Thanks alot.

Comment: I don't see debug option in plugin manager even after `geany-plugins` installation.

Comment: @AbinashDash OK, geany-debugger plugins is not exist in some distro like my debian 10. I compile it from source to use it. https://www.geany.org/download/releases/

Comment: Hi if you right click on the messages tab it comes up with a list with it on. @shahar_m

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation most the the controls offered by this plugin are pretty standards (Breakpoints, Watches).

However this page may help you to start using the debugger: http://geanydbg.sourceforge.net/walkthrough.htm.

Comment: I have some experience in the Dev C++ debugger and I know how breakpoints and watches work but I can't understand what are environmental variable,Target and autos. I followed the procedure here [http://geanydbg.sourceforge.net/walkthrough.htm](http://geanydbg.sourceforge.net/walkthrough.htm) but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found something that works here in this [forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1400668) but still the step into button is still a little buggy :P
Will update when I get it correct.